# Align y-axis title of high charts to begin exactly at 0 position

Tags: highcharts

I have my high charts y axis title of varying length between 15 and 30. I want it to begin exactly at the start of the axis. The problem with the current code is the longer titles are pushed towards the left thereby cutting themselves, whereas the shorter ones are more towards the right.

```
yAxis: {
   title: {
     text: titleString,
     align: 'high',
     rotation: 0,
     y: -20,
     x: -10, //Trying to vary this value.
     style: {
        font-size: '11px',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
     }
   }
}
```

How to set the x property in such a way that the title always begin at the 0 position (`x:0` is not working)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `attr()` function on title element and set plotLeft value.

```
chart: {
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var chart = this,
                    yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
                    left = yAxis.toPixels(0);

                yAxis.axisTitle.attr({
                    y: left
                });
            }
        }
    },
```

Example:
 - http://jsfiddle.net/s8nq3huq/2/

Comment: It will set the title for the chart - not the title for the y-axis right? It doesn't make any difference to the look, but from the code correctness perspective ...